# What is the syntax error in this formula?

Tags: formula

```
AND(
TEXT(Status) != ( TEXT( PRIORVALUE(Status) )  = "Converted To Opportunity"),
TEXT(Status) != ( TEXT( PRIORVALUE(Status) )  = "Rejected")
)
```

Comment: Construction A != B = C is not really correct. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: System will restrict user to change Lead status from “Converted to Opportunity" to Open/ Rejected/ Accepted.
Further more status accepted can not be open

Comment: AND(
( TEXT( PRIORVALUE(Status) )  = "Converted To Opportunity"),
  OR( TEXT(Status)  = "Open", TEXT(Status)  = "Rejected", TEXT(Status)  = "Accepted")
)

Comment: You should include the use case in the question rather than just the formula as otherwise it is not really possible to provide any help - see [ask]

Comment: @kurunve looks like you have the answer.  Please post.

Answer (score 1):

To forbid changing Lead status from “Converted to Opportunity" to "Open"/"Rejected"/"Accepted", next formula may be used:

```
 AND(
     TEXT( PRIORVALUE(Status) ) = "Converted To Opportunity",
     OR( TEXT(Status) = "Open",
         TEXT(Status) = "Rejected",
         TEXT(Status) = "Accepted"
       )
 )
```

First condition under AND operand checks if the old status is "Converted to Opportunity", and new one is equal to Open **or** Rejected **or** Accepted.